# How to make parent element the same size as his child which is absolutely positioned to his grandparent?

Tags: html, css

I have a grandparent div `.grandparent` with an image element `.child-image` inside which is absolutely positioned in relation to `.grandparent`. I want the wrapper element `.parent-wrapper` (which wraps the image) to have the same width and height as the its child `.child-image`. Is it possible? I tried almost everything but still can't figure it out.

Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MRNwoJ?editors=1100

```css
.grandparent {
  height: 650px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 642px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  background-color: #464646;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent-wrapper {
  height: unset;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.child-image {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <img class="child-image" src="https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/rebrand/co_create/desktop/dropbox_digital_desktop_02-vflq-5NiU.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the img needs to be positioned absolutely?

Comment: @MrLister Because the grandparent must have `height: 650px` so the image should be always centered both horizontaly and verticaly. Hence absolute positioning in relation to `.grandparent` div

Comment: You can do centered positioning without `position: absolute`

Comment: You could use flexbox instead, but also if you did use absolute positioning and wanted the parent to be the same size as the image, why not just absolutely position the parent?  There seems to be something really wrong with the way this is being done.  Actually - what's the point of the parent if it's just the same size as the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why are you making all this complicated. I have changed the code in a simpler form, hope this is what you want. if you want something else specific please do comment.

```css
.grandparent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    background-color: #464646;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .parent-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  img {
   max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <img class="child-image" src="https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/rebrand/co_create/desktop/dropbox_digital_desktop_02-vflq-5NiU.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position absolute from the child image and give it to the parent div, this way the parent div will have the same position and size as the child.

```
.grandparent {
  height: 650px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 642px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  background-color: #464646;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.parent-wrapper {
  height: 100;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 300px);
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
   height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.child-image {
  display: block;
  min-height: 1px;
  cursor: unset;
```

}